# Scale and change an element from an image to a word, depending on scroll position.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have seen some scrolling effects for example on Google SketchUp's site, their banner is initially "built into the page" and then it seems to pop out and remain stuck at the top after a certain position down (scrolling).

Google Plus seems to have some special effects as well, like changing the banner entirely once the scrolling has reached a certain position.

Attached is what I am trying to accomplish. A square logo is on the right, and then when the page is scrolled down, the logo starts to scale to the same height as the banner/header / fade and then becomes a word rather than the image.

What am I looking at here? jQuery or javascript? How do I track the scrolling and connect the two?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a combination of a scroll event handler in JS and CSS transforms.

Comment: Thanks Rory McCrossan, I'll check that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it what you want to achieve?

http://jsfiddle.net/agdbd8x6/15/

If so, it is quite easy. If you use jQuery, attach 'scroll' event handler and check current scroll position. Show the image only with zero scroll position:

```
var img = $('#image');
var txt = $('#text');

$(".container").scroll(function(){                                
    txt.text('Scroll position = ' + $(this).scrollTop());
    var showImage = $(this).scrollTop() == 0;
    if (showImage){
        img.css('display', 'inline');
        txt.hide();
    }
    else{
        img.hide();
        txt.css('display', 'inline-block');
    }
});
```

Comment: Whoa that's so cool with the live counter, thank you very much!